# pandoc related error on saving rmarkdown file

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I am not being able to knit R markdown to pdf and I suspect it is due to a pandoc issue because every time I try saving the R markdown file I get the message "Error creating notebook: pandoc document converstion failed with error 64."

I am using RStudio "Prairie Trillium" Release (1db809b8, 2022-05-16) for macOS on macOS Monterey Version 12.4 with R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22).

What could be causing this error message? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing the input document. Error 64 is a `PandocParseError`, and the most likely explanation is a problem in a YAML metadata block.

Comment: I copied the content into a new Rmd file and, apparently, what was causing the problem was an attempt to write a note preceded and followed by a line across the page at the end. I was using '---' to draw the line. When I got rid of the final line, the problem went away. Thank you. Your answer about 'not seeing the input' made go through the input in more detail and helped solve the problem.

Comment: That makes sense: R Markdown / pandoc treats `---` as delimiters for YAML blocks under some circumstances. This can be avoided by surrounding them by blank lines, or by using a different syntax for horizontal lines (like `- - -` or `* * *`). So it was a YAML problem, although it wasn't supposed to be treated as YAML.